# I want to call a function of the provider class from within the NetworkImage widget

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-provider, mobile-development, flutter-widget

I want to show the image returned from the endpoint that I requested, in the NetworkImage widget. Each image to return has a separate id. I need to update this id when making request to endpoint. How can I do that? I use provider class.

```
//provider
class InfoDetailsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
 HttpService _httpService = HttpService();
 Future<StorageItem> getImage(String imageId ) async {
    StorageItem storageItem;
    _httpService.initWithToken(authToken);
    final urlImage= "http://example../$imageId";
    try {
      final result = await _httpService.request(url: urlImage, method: Method.GET);
      if (result != null) {
        if (result is d.Response) {
          var responseData = result.data;     
          storageItem=responseData.forEach((key,value){ });
          notifyListeners();
          return storageItem;
        }
      }
    } on d.DioError catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    return storageItem;
  }
}
```

I want to call getImage function in Info Details Screen to display image. Is it possible to call function with in NetworkImage widget?

```
//Screen
class InfoDetailsState extends State<InfoDetailsScreen> {
  var _isInit = true;
  var _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });   
      Provider.of<InfoDetailsProvider>(context).getImage(imageId);
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

...

   return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: RefreshIndicator(
        ....
          child: SlidingUpPanel(
                 ...
                  body: SafeArea(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(                        
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              image: NetworkImage(

                                **  //Should I call function here?**
                              ),
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            ),
                          ));
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, the solution is

```
InkWell(
      onTap: callFunction(),
      child: Container(
        child: NetworkImage(),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
           image: DecorationImage(
             image: NetworkImage(
                 **  //Should I call function here?**
                 ),
             fit: BoxFit.fill,
           ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

and you can define your function that will call provider's function inside the `build` method like

```
callFunction() {
      Provider.of<CarsProvider>(context, listen: false).yourFunction();
    }
```

if you have further more question, ask in comment. :)

Comment: I want to show the image returned by this function directly in the network image widget without using button clik(onTap). Is there any solution for that?

Comment: In my code, the function callFunction is being executed without onTap method. Just give it a try.

Comment: It works! It not only function but access the data from the state
Thanks mate